# Download files with express js request module

Tags: node.js, express, request, download

I'm downloading a file in the code bellow...

```
var download = function(uri, filename, callback, path) {

  request
  .get(uri)
  .on('response', function (response) {
    var responseType = (response.headers['content-type'] || '').split(';')[0].trim();
    var ext = mime.extension(responseType);

    filename += '.' + ext;

    var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
                    .on('finish', function () {

                    });

    this.pipe(fileStream);

    path = filename; //this doesn't work, the path by reference gets empty

  });

  //I've tried setting a variable here with the file name's value and 
  //returning it here but it's returning empty value

};
```

Everything works fine but i need a way to return the filename to the function caller, but it comes empty, i can't set even a variable by reference with this filename value inside the request function.. Could somebody help me? thanks in advance

Comment: Definitely it's a duplicate. TL;DR in your code you have an unused callback function, return calculated value throw this function. In other words, your callback function should be called by "download" subroutine when result is ready.

Comment: Thanks guys! It worked !